# Hardy-Littlewood maximal function algorithm

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, algorithms, computational-mathematics, simple-functions

There exists implemented algorithm which compute the [Hardy-Littlewood maximal function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardy%E2%80%93Littlewood_maximal_function) at least for reasonably simple non-trivial cases? E.g. piecewise linear functions?